# PHP remove arrays by nested key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have some arrays that I'd like to unset based on a key.

For example, let's say I have this array:

```
$array = array(
  'one' => array('item' => '1'),
  'two' => array('item' => '2')
);
```

If I want to unset the nested array with key 'two', I could do:

```
unset($array['two'])
```

or if I wanted to unset just the item array for key 'two', I could do:

```
unset($array['two']['item'])
```

I want to dynamically delete array items based on known keys.  So for example, I know I want to delete `['two']['item']`.

How do I pass those two arguments to a method, that can then be appended to an array?

Example:

```
//This works fine if it's only the first item in the array
function deleteArray($keys)
{
  unset($this->array[$keys]);
}
```

But when we want to delete nested items, this would not work.  I could pass in the keys as an array such as `array('two', 'item')` and build the index off of this, but not sure how....

Any help would be great! thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function delete(&$array, $keys)
{
   $key = array_shift($keys);

   if (count($keys) == 0)
      unset($array[$key]);
   else
      delete($array[$key], $keys);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with a recursive function:

```
function deleteArray(&$array, $keys) {
    if ( count($keys) == 1 )
       unset( $array[$keys[0]] );
    else
    {
       $k = array_shift($keys);
       deleteArray($array[$k],$keys); 
    }
}
deleteArray($this->arr, array("three","item","blabla")); // This erase $this->array["three"]["item"]["blabla"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteArray($keys)
{
$keyarray = explode($keys, " ");
   unset($this->array[$keyarray[0]][$keyarray[1]]);
}
```

I edited it a bit (won't work!) maybe somebody could continue that. Maybe it is possible with a while() ...

Comment: What if there are 10 arguments? Ideally, the number of arguments would be dynamic.

Comment: Well no, sry I don't know if that's possible.